# After upgrading to Solr v8.11.1 from v7.7.2 search result is very different

Tags: solr, lucene, solrcloud, solr8

We have upgraded solr version from 7.7.2. to 8.11.1, after that we are facing issue for search result. Less result are not matching for both version. Our document list are same as it is.
Also we have using same schema and fields.
Can someone please help us on it what can be possible reason or solution or or any algorithm change happened for v8 which can result into differ?

Answer (score 0):

We recently upgraded from Solr 7.3 to Solr 8.9 running Solr Cloud. We had an issue with it showing a different number of documents even though we took a backup in Solr 7 and restored to Solr 8. Eventually we discovered that in Solr 8 there were some major changes to nested documents, we do not use nested documents in our environment, however in Solr 8 it was causing some of our documents to appear with the same id resulting in those documents appearing twice causing the discrepancy. We ended up taking another full backup and then deleting all our collections/configsets. After that we deleted the *root* field from the managed-schema and restored. After the restore our document counts matched up. Hope this helps.

Comment: We have used same manage schema which we used in 7. And there is no root field is there. :(

Comment: May be possible that search algorithm is changed for solr 8. Not sure what happening.